# Is Jean Jacket an alien?

Tags: nope-2022

Jordan Peele's 2022 film *Nope* centers on the Haywood siblings as they try to capture evidence of a UFO on film. Early on, there is evidence that a UFO is abducting the Haywoods' horses (and perhaps people as well), and that the Haywoods' neighbor, a theme park owner named Jupe, is exploiting that.

Later, it is revealed that the UFO, nicknamed Jean Jacket by the Haywoods,

> is not a ship, but a creature that has eaten many horses and people.

Watching the movie, I thought that Jean Jacket was an alien, but really there is no reason to assume that. For all we know, it could be an as-of-yet undiscovered creature native to Earth. Has Jordan Peele or anyone else who worked on the film spoken about this?

Comment: "its origin is shrouded in mystery" sayeth the maker

Comment: I won't speak for the movie but it may be of interest that the theory of UFOs being livestock eating creatures has been around since the 1970s and this "Overlords of the UFO" got a lot of screening in the 1990s on cable like TNT channel. scene link https://youtu.be/S3Xl8xE974A?t=4945

Comment: I think there was speculation that “Nope” stood for “Not of planet earth”, although that still works as a title, as it’s the assumption the siblings are working under for most of the movie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is deliberately vague. However, some of the people involved in the film seem to hint that Jean Jacket is more otherworldly than not.

One of the scientific consultants for the film, John O. Dabiri, was interviewed about the creature's design (emphasis mine):

> [...] John O. Dabiri, an engineering professor at CalTech whose research studies animal behavior and fluid dynamics to create new technologies.
>
> In a phone conversation with Thrillist, Dabiri went in depth on how he and Peele's team created this creature, which animal behaviors they used for inspiration, and whether there could be more Jean Jackets hiding in plain sight amongst the clouds.

> **Dabiri:** [...] That last scene, where you're seeing the display from Jean Jacket, with those sort of ribbons coming out and flapping, we had some interesting conversations about what that might look like in a real animal versus what he [Jordan Peele] had in his mind. He really wanted that rectangular geometry for the eye, that flapping motion. **You don't typically see that too much in biology, those really regular features, but, in a sense, I think that was intentional here. To say that there are parts of this, even by earthly biological standards, that are bizarre and really not of this world.**

<sup>- [*Inside the Eerie UFO Design for Jordan Peele's 'Nope'* — Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/nope-movie-ufo-design)</sup>

Jordan Peele has described the movie as an "[alien movie](https://youtu.be/__SNN6xpFx4?t=1488)"* and a "[flying saucer film](https://youtu.be/I-KJ-BkuTJE?t=203)"†. It seems that he intended to give the vibe that Jean Jacket is an alien creature (even though it is vague what the creature actually is).

<sup>* [*Around the Table with Jordan Peele and the Cast of 'Nope'* — Entertainment Weekly](https://youtu.be/__SNN6xpFx4?t=1488)

† [*Jordan Peele Discusses Ideation Of New Horror Film "Nope"* — Today](https://youtu.be/I-KJ-BkuTJE?t=203)</sup>

Daniel Kaluuya (OJ), Keke Palmer (Emerald), Brandon Perea (Angel), and Steven Yeun (Jupe) reacted to the popular fan theory that "Nope" means "Not of Planet Earth". They outright denied the other fan theories (or commented that they're "interesting"), but they had a different reaction to this theory, suggesting that it is deliberately vague if the creature is "Not of Planet Earth".

> **Steven:** Mine's just a tweet that says, "NOPE = Not of Planet Earth."
> **Keke:** I seen that one.
> **Brandon:** I've been seeing that one.
> **Keke:** It could be coded.
> **Steven:** Yeah. All right. You just getting noises from us.
> [*Daniel and Steven jokingly mumble*]
> **Keke:** I've seen the, not a planet earth one a lot. I mean, the thing is, any of these there could be elements and vibes of it, but it's not it exactly. They have the Peele-ian vibes.

<sup>- [*NOPE Fan Theories with Keke Palmer, Daniel Kaluuya, Steven Yeun and Brandon Perea* — Vanity Fair](https://youtu.be/fnNMs3O23uE?t=283)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

That was intentionally left ambiguous by the makers.

> *Rocheron got involved from a very early stage, while Peele was still
> working on drafts of the screenplay. “He had some ideas of creating an
> iconic flying saucer that would then become another creature, a bit
> more wind-based and we talked a lot about the concepts,” Rocheron
> said. “Very quickly we landed on this idea of kind of like minimalism
> in the design.” Rocheron said that this meant being “very spare with
> details, that everything has a function,” and also creating an alien
> design language – that Jean Jacket was a “creature of the winds.”
> **While Rocheron referred to the creature as an alien during our
> interview, he reached back out via email to say that he thought it was
> maybe a terrestrial creature that had been around, maybe forever. He
> thinks Peele feels the same way about Jean Jacket.***
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Nope’ VFX Supervisor Reveals Secrets of Jordan Peele’s Horror Epic: From Gordy to Jean Jacket](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/nope-vfx-supervisor-reveals-secrets-163900040.html)</sup></sub>